# 4 Stroke Lawn mower Engine will not fire

Tags: engine

I am looking for suggestions of what to try next.

## Problem

I have small ride on lawn mower with a 4 stroke Briggs and Stratton engine. It will not start and doesn't seem to fire.

## What I have tried

1. Fresh petrol.
2. Pulled plug out and checked for spark. Good spark but plug is a little black.
3. Sprayed some carb cleaner in air intake (I didn't have any easy start), engine fired for as long as I sprayed further confirming ignition. Made me think it must be fuel related.
4. Removed carb, sprayed some cleaner inside, blow though jets with air line. Reassembled, still no firing, not even a splutter of trying.

So I am looking for ideas. Spark seems to exist due to firing with fuel sprayed into air intake. Carb all clean, but no firing. Makes me think there is still no fuel (carb bowl is full btw, I checked that I have supply to the carb.

Edit: Borrowed a compression tester and got a 100psi reading repeatedly when cranking. I think I will give  the carb another clean as suggested by trying to disassemble. Thanks all. I will post an update.

Comment: The orifices in a carb can't be simply cleaned with compressed air. If it was stored poorly  you'll need to disassemble the carb and clean it thoroughly. I don't know what a "flue" would be.

Comment: Change the spark plug.  Spark outside and inside can be different, more pressure inside.

Comment: Yeah, I would wonder if there's something wrong with the ignition.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am going to try disassembling the carb and then spark plug as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard things that can go wrong on this or a generator are:

1. Spark is bad (broken wire, bad plug, etc.  You can test it.  Or plug needs to be cleaned or gapped
2. Fuel is missing, or has turned into jelly or clogged fuel filter
3. Carb is not clean -- needs to be taken apart and cleaned, or bad float or a bunch of other things that can happen if you leave ethanol gas in it for a long time
4. Air filter is bad, clogged, or whatnot.
5. Something broke internally and the engine is shot.